# react-quill is working well on next dev mode but it's not shown on production mode(=release mode)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, react-quill

I've been suffered from an issue about react-quill in typescript.

As I said on title, It's working well on next.js dev mode(with command `next dev`) but its toolbar is not shown on production mode(with command `next build` and `next start`)

Is there any idea? I'd like to hear from guru like you.

```js
// IBRichEditor/index.tsx
import { useRef, useMemo, useState } from 'react'
import ReactQuill, { Quill } from 'react-quill'
import 'react-quill/dist/quill.snow.css' // ES6
import { AxiosError } from 'axios'
import { AuthAPIKit } from 'src/hooks/APITools/APIKit'
import ImageResize from 'quill-image-resize'
import { IBRichEditorProps } from './types'
import { useSnackbar } from 'notistack'

Quill.register('modules/ImageResize', ImageResize)

const IBRichEditor = ({ defaultValue, onChangeEditor }: IBRichEditorProps) => {
  const QuillRef = useRef<ReactQuill>()
  const { enqueueSnackbar } = useSnackbar()

  const imageHandler = () => {
    const input = document.createElement('input')
    const formData = new FormData()
    let url = ''

    input.setAttribute('type', 'file')
    input.setAttribute('accept', 'image/*')
    input.click()

    input.onchange = async () => {
      const file = input.files
      if (file !== null) {
        formData.append('files', file[0])

        try {
          const res = await AuthAPIKit.post('/s3Upload', formData, {
            headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
            },
          })
          url = res.data.IBparams[0].Location

          const range = QuillRef.current?.getEditor().getSelection()?.index
          console.log(QuillRef)
          if (range !== null && range !== undefined) {
            let quill = QuillRef.current?.getEditor()

            quill?.setSelection(range, 1)

            quill?.clipboard.dangerouslyPasteHTML(
              range,
              `<img src=${url} alt="이미지 태그가 삽입됩니다." />`,
            )
          }

          return { ...res, success: true }
        } catch (error) {
          const err = error as AxiosError
          return { ...err.response, success: false }
        }
      }
    }
  }

  const modules = useMemo(
    () => ({
      toolbar: {
        container: [
          ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'strike', 'blockquote'],
          [{ size: ['small', false, 'large', 'huge'] }, { color: [] }],
          [
            { list: 'ordered' },
            { list: 'bullet' },
            { indent: '-1' },
            { indent: '+1' },
            { align: [] },
          ],
          [
            'image',
            // 'video',
          ],
        ],
        handlers: {
          image: imageHandler,
        },
      },
      ImageResize: {
        parchment: Quill.import('parchment'),
      },
    }),
    [],
  )

  return (
    <>
      <ReactQuill
        ref={QuillRef}
        // style={{ maxHeight: '50%' }}
        defaultValue={defaultValue}
        onChange={(content, delta, source, editor) => {
          onChangeEditor(editor.getHTML())
          console.log(QuillRef)
        }}
        modules={modules}
        theme="snow"
        placeholder="test"
      />
    </>
  )
}

IBRichEditor.defaultProps = {}

export default IBRichEditor
```

```js
...
...

const IBRichEditor = dynamic(
  import('src/components/common/IBRichEditor/index'),
  { ssr: false },
)


const NewsUpdateModal = ({
  handleClose,
  open,
  newsItem,
  newsList,
  setNewsList,
}: NewsUpdateModalProps) => {
...

return (
<RegContentInputBox>
   <RegInputLabel>News Title</RegInputLabel>
   <RegContentInputQuill>
      <IBRichEditor
        defaultValue={inputData.content}
        onChangeEditor={onChangeEditor}
      />
   </RegContentInputQuill>
  </RegContentInputBox>
 )
}
```

## dev mode: it's okay

[image: dev mode: it's okay]

## production mode: it's not shown

[image: production mode: not shown]

Comment: did you fine a solution? facing the same problem

Comment: Unfortunately not, I'm sorry say this. If I find out something, I'll write it here.

Answer (score 0):

As of what I understood, next js is server-side rendering framework and react-quill interact as client so we need to import quill dynamically, in that way you'll be able to see in prod build as well

```
> import dynamic from 'next/dynamic'
> const ReactQuill = dynamic(() => import('react-quill'), { ssr: false });
```

For me this worked, if still not working in your case then I'll suggest to inspect and check the element section for editor and cross check the css styling part because there might be some other data are overriding editor toolbar part(one of my colleague faced css related issue)